# ReactのcomponentWillUnmountでbeforeunload的なことがしたい

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Reactでbeforeunloadを使いたいのですが、windowのスコープの範囲に収まらないbeforeunloadイベントを拾えないため、componentWillUnmountが呼ばれたタイミングでconfirm関数を呼び、キャンセルされればcomponentWillUnmountをpreventしたいです。
やりたいことは以下のような感じです。

```
componentWillUnmount: function(e) {
  var result = confirm('遷移してもよろしいですか？');
  if (!result) {
    // prevent unmount
  }
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

componentDidMountの時listenerを追加で、componentWillUnmountの時外せばいいと思います。

```
onUnload(event) {
  var result = confirm('遷移してもよろしいですか？');
  if (!result) {
    // prevent unmount
  }　　　　
　
}

componentDidMount() {
   window.addEventListener("beforeunload", this.onUnload)
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", this.onUnload)
}
```